# Spring validation keeps validating the wrong argument

Tags: spring, bean-validation

I have a controller with a web method that looks like this:

```
public Response registerDevice(
    @Valid final Device device, 
    @RequestBody final Tokens tokens
) {...}
```

And a validator that looks like this:

```
public class DeviceValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Device.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        // Do magic
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get Spring to validate the Device argument which is being generated by an interceptor. But every time I try, it validates the tokens argument instead.

I've tried using `@InitBinder` to specify the validator, `@Validated` instead of `@Valid`and registering `MethodValidationPostProcessor` classes. So far with no luck.

Either the validator is not called at all, or tokens argument is validated when I was the Device argument validated.

I'm using Spring 4.1.6 and Hibernate validator 5.1.3.

Can anyone offer any clues as to what I'm doing wrong? I've searched the web all afternoon trying to sort this out. Can't believe that the validation area of spring is still as messed up as it was 5 years ago :-(

Comment: Why are you submitting both a model attribute and son payload? Looks weird to me in the first place. The `@Valid` should also have the `@ModelAttribute` annotation, next to that if you want to access validation errors you need to have an attribute directly following the `Device` argument. However I would say that you are trying to do multiple things with a single method and that is what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @ModelAttribute didn't work. It just created an empty Device and bypassed my HandlerMethodArgumentResolver which creates the object. I'm not sure what you are talking about in regard to two different things. The device is built dynamically from header information, and the tokens come from the http request body. They are not part of the same model at this point. Whats confusing me is that the validation stuff's doco is rather murky and seems to only be applicable if you have model classes which are annotated internally. I just want to valid a single argument using a validator.

Comment: I made assumptions here and you didn't explain you had a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. Validation generally will only work for model attributes or request bodies not for other objects. You will have to put it in your custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, you can take a look at the `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` how validation is implemented there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. Have now solved it after two days of messing about with all sorts of variations. If there is one thing Spring's validation lets you do - it's come up with an incredible array of things that don't work! But back to my solution.

Basically what I needed was a way to manually create request mapping arguments, validate them and then ensure that no matter whether it was a success or failure, that the caller always received a custom JSON response. Doing this proved a lot harder than I thought because despite the number of blog posts and stackoverflow answers, I never found a complete solution. So I've endeavoured to outline each piece of the puzzle needed to achieve what I wanted.

*Note: in the following code samples, I've generalised the names of things to help clarify whats custom and whats not.*

### Configuration

Although several blog posts I read talked about various classes such as the `MethodValidationPostProcessor`, in the end I found I didn't need anything setup beyond the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation. The default resolvers etc proved to be what I needed.

### Request Mapping

My final request mapping signatures looked like this:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public MyMsgObject handleRequest (
    @Valid final MyHeaderObj myHeaderObj, 
    @RequestBody final MyRequestPayload myRequestPayload
    ) {...}
```

You will note here that unlike just about every blog post and sample I found, I have two objects being passed to the method. The first is an object that I want to dynamically generate from the headers. The second is a deserialised object from the JSON payload. Other objects could just as easily be included such as path arguments etc. Try something like this without the code below and you will get a wide variety of weird and wonderful errors.

The tricky part that caused me all the pain was that I wanted to validate the `myHeaderObj` instance, and NOT validate the `myRequestPayload` instance. This caused quite a headache to resolve.

Also note the `MyMsgObject` result object. Here I want to return an object that will be serialised out to JSON. Including when exceptions occur as this class contains error fields that need to be populated in addition to the HttpStatus code.

### Controller Advice

Next I created an `ControllerAdvice` class which contained the binding for validation and a general error trap.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyControllerAdvice {

    @Autowired
    private MyCustomValidator customValidator;

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        if (binder.getTarget() == null) {
            // Plain arguments have a null target.
            return;
        }
        if (MyHeaderObj.class.isAssignableFrom(binder.getTarget().getClass())) {
            binder.addValidators(this.customValidator);
        }
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody
    public MyMsgObject handleException(Exception e) {
        MyMsgObject myMsgObject = new MyMsgObject();
        myMsgObject.setStatus(MyStatus.Failure);
        myMsgObject.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        return myMsgObject;
    }
}
```

Two things going on here. The first is registering the validator. Note that we have to check the type of the argument. This is because `@InitBinder` is called for each argument to the `@RequestMapping` and we only want the validator on the `MyHeaderObj` argument. If we don't do this, exceptions will be thrown when Spring attempts to apply the validator to arguments it's not valid for.

The second thing is the exception handler. We have to use `@ResponseBody` to ensure that Spring treats the returned object as something to be serialised out. Otherwise we will just get the standard HTML exception report.

### Validator

Here we use a pretty standard validator implementation.

```
@Component
public class MyCustomValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return MyHeaderObj.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        ...
        errors.rejectValue("fieldName", "ErrorCode", "Invalid ..."); 
    }
}
```

One thing that I still don't really get with this is the `supports(Class<?> clazz)` method. I would have thought that Spring uses this method to test arguments to decide if this validator should apply. But it doesn't. Hence all the code in the `@InitBinder` to decide when to apply this validator.

### The Argument Handler

This is the biggest piece of code. Here we need to generate the `MyHeaderObj` object to be passed to the `@RequestMapping`. Spring will auto detect this class.

```
public class MyHeaderObjArgumentHandler implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return MyHeaderObj.class.isAssignableFrom(parameter.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(
        MethodParameter parameter, 
        ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
        NativeWebRequest webRequest, 
        WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

        // Code to generate the instance of MyHeaderObj!
        MyHeaderObj myHeaderObj = ...;

        // Call validators if the argument has validation annotations.
        WebDataBinder binder = binderFactory.createBinder(webRequest, myHeaderObj, parameter.getParameterName());
        this.validateIfApplicable(binder, parameter);
        if (binder.getBindingResult().hasErrors()) {
            throw new MyCustomException(myHeaderObj);
        }
        return myHeaderObj;
    }

    protected void validateIfApplicable(WebDataBinder binder, MethodParameter methodParam) {
        Annotation[] annotations = methodParam.getParameterAnnotations();
        for (Annotation ann : annotations) {
            Validated validatedAnn = AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(ann, Validated.class);
            if (validatedAnn != null || ann.annotationType().getSimpleName().startsWith("Valid")) {
                Object hints = (validatedAnn != null ? validatedAnn.value() : AnnotationUtils.getValue(ann));
                Object[] validationHints = (hints instanceof Object[] ? (Object[]) hints : new Object[] { hints });
                binder.validate(validationHints);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main job of this class is to use whatever means it requires to build the argument (`myHeaderObj`). Once built it then proceeds to call the Spring validators to check this instance. If there is a problem (as detected by checking the returned errors), it then throws an exception that the `@ExceptionHandler`'s can detect and process.

Note the `validateIfApplicable(WebDataBinder binder, MethodParameter methodParam)` method. This is code I found in a number of Spring's classes. It's job is to detect if any argument has a `@Validated` or `@Valid` annotation and if so, call the associated validators. By default, Spring does not do this for custom argument handlers like this one, so it's up to us to add this functionality. Seriously Spring ???? No AbstractSomething ????

### The last piece, explicit Exception catches

Lastly I also needed to catch more explicit exceptions. For example the `MyCustomException` thrown above. So here I created a second `@ControllerAdvise`.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) // Make sure we get the highest priority.
public class MyCustomExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Response handleException(MyCustomException e) {
        MyMsgObject myMsgObject = new MyMsgObject();
        myMsgObject.setStatus(MyStatus.Failure);
        myMsgObject.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        return myMsgObject;
    }
}
```

Although superficially the similar to the general exception handler. There is one different. We need to specify the `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` annotation. Without this, Spring will just execute the first exception handler that matches the thrown exception. Regardless of whether there is a better matching handler or not. So we use this annotation to ensure that this exception handler is given precedence over the general one.

### Summary

This solution works well for me. I'm not sure that I've got the best solution and there may be Spring classes which I've not found which can help. I hope this helps anyone with the same or similar problems.